# TBB version 3.6.2 is unable or slow to open many sites including this one

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Utilizing TBB version 3.6.2, it is slow or one is unable to open many sites including this site (https://tor.stackexchange.com). Anybody else have similar problem? Any solution?

Comment: How did you do the update? If you unpacked TBB to a new directory and start it from there, you'll use a new set of guard nodes. It might be the case that they are slower than the old ones. Do you have the old installation? If yes, can you compare what relays are used with the old version and with 3.6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful hint by Jens Kubieziel has helped to solve this problem. Since one will get new guard nodes if one unpack TBB to a new directory, there is a chance that new guards are slower than old guards. If the problem is significant enough to slow the browsing operation to a nil, one might decide to unpack the package to a new location again or use the old guards if one see fit and/or change the slow guards in any appropriate way to get a reasonable speed. The only thing is one should be careful that slow speed might be a trick by an adversary to encourage one to change the guards.